# How do I prove that a circle is mapped to an ellipse under orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

> [image]
>
> The figure also shows the orthogonal projection $\tilde{C}$ of C onto a second plane $\tilde{P}$ through T, the
> angle between the planes being α. As you probably know [or exercise] $\tilde{C}$ is in fact an ellipse, the
> original circle C having been compressed in a direction perpendicular to T. Thus it is clear that the
> curvature $\tilde{κ}$ of $\tilde{C}$ at p is less than the original curvature κ.

How do I do the exercise i.e: prove that the circle gets sent to an ellipse under orthogonal projection? This is the first time the book introduces orthogonal projections ( I think?) and I am not sure what relevant properties of it can be used to prove the situation.

---

### What I know so far:

$$ \tilde{\sigma}= \sigma \cos \alpha$$

Comment: How much do you know about the various lengths shown in the figure, especially $\sigma,$ $\tilde\sigma,$ and (if I read the figure correctly) $\epsilon$? It looks like you have been given coordinates of the points of the circle and its projection with enough information to write the equations of both the circle and its projection in the coordinates of their respective planes. Then all you would need to do is to confirm that the equation of the projection is the equation of an ellipse.

Comment: Hmm right, you rephrased the problem how do I write the equation of projeciton ?

Comment: @666User666 The projection maps $\,(\tilde\epsilon, \tilde\sigma) \mapsto (\epsilon=\tilde\epsilon, \sigma = \tilde\sigma / \cos \alpha)\,$. The circle in plane $\tilde p$ has an equation of the form $\,(\tilde\epsilon - a)^2+(\tilde\sigma-b)^2=r^2\,$. Substituting $\,\tilde\epsilon,\tilde\sigma$ in terms of $\,\epsilon,\sigma\,$ gives the equation of the projection of the circle in plane $\,p\,$.

Comment: How do I prove that lengths parallel to $\epsilon$ are preserved? @dxiv

Comment: @666User666 Lengths alongside the axis $\tau$ are preserved. A segment in $\tilde p$ parallel to $\tau$ and its projection onto $p$ are the opposite sides of a rectangle, thus equal.

Comment: How do I prove that rectangles get mapped to rectangles? @dxiv

Comment: @666User666 Not all rectangles get mapped to rectangles, but those with a side parallel to $\tau$ do. It should become more obvious if you draw the figure.